# waiting for __doPostBack() function to complete

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I don't have the source code of a web application in .Net neither the access to the database.

And with Greasemonkey I use JavaScript.

In the source code of HTML I have :

```
<input ... onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MidContent$GridView4','Page$10')">
```

So in greasmonkey script I put

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$MidContent$GridView4','Page$10');
/* others instructions */
```

But the others instructions doesn't wait the __doPostBack() function to complete.

I want nothing to execute until the __doPostBack() have not finish.

PS: I'm not good at .NET just with JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait on the \_\_doPostBack method to complete in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504472/how-to-wait-on-the-dopostback-method-to-complete-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: 
        {
            '__EVENTTARGET': '<%=YourButtonName.ClientID %>'
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert("ok");
    }).fail(function (p1, p2, p3) {
        alert("error");
    });
```