# How do I wait for a JavaScript __doPostBack call through Selenium and WebDriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, asp.net-ajax, dopostback

I am facing a rare kind of issue while Automating through Selenium/Python while trying to fill out two fields on a website. My script fills out the first field i.e. *ORIGIN CITY* pretty fine. I have induced *WebDriverWait* for the second field *DELIVERY ADDRESS*.

My guess the *DELIVERY ADDRESS* field is pretty much *clickable* even before the waiter is induced.

But the *ORIGIN CITY* field have a *JavaScript* associated through `onchange` event as follows :

```
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'DrpCity\',\'\')', 0)"
```

ORIGIN CITY HTML :

```html
<li>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select name="DrpCity" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'DrpCity\',\'\')', 0)" id="DrpCity" class="inputStyle">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">Origin City</option>
  <option value="3">Bangalore</option>
  <option value="6">Chennai</option>
  <option value="8">Delhi - NCR</option>
  <option value="10">Hyderabad</option>
  <option value="7">Kochi</option>
  <option value="12">Kolkata</option>
  <option value="13">Mumbai</option>
  <option value="15">Pune</option>

 </select>
    <span id="ReqCity" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Select your city !</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

DELIVERY ADDRESS HTML :

```html
<li>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="" id="div_AddPopup" style="display: none;">
      *Cars will not be delivered at Metro Stations, Malls or Public Place.
    </div>
    <input name="txtPickUp" type="text" id="txtPickUp" class="inputStyle locMark" placeholder="Delivery Address" onfocus="showOnKeyPress(); return true;" onblur="hideOnKeyPress(); return true;">

    <span id="ReqPickUp" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Enter Delivery Address !</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Once the *JavaScript* finishes it clears up the text from the *DELIVERY ADDRESS* field.

I did had a look at the Java Client's  *ExpectedConditions* as *jsReturnsValue* which is not there for the *Selenium Python Client*.

Website :   https://www.avis.co.in/

My Code :

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.avis.co.in")
    mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("DrpCity"))
    mySelect.select_by_visible_text("Pune")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='txtPickUp']"))).send_keys("XYZ")
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found, the easiest way to deal with these JS `postbacks`, is to wait for the element that is affected by the **load** to go *stale* or not be found.

Here is an example function:

```
def waitForElementRemoved(Element, WaitCount, WaitTime):
    ElementRemoved = False
    WaitTry = 0
    while not ElementRemoved:
        try:
            if WaitTry > WaitCount:
                raise Exception("Element not removed from page in alloted time")
            Test = Element.text
            WaitTry += 1
            time.sleep(WaitTime)
        except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
            ElementRemoved = True
```

And then I would pick an element that is affected by this `postback load` and pass it to the function along with some timing arguments.

such as:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.avis.co.in")
removedElement = driver.find_element_by_id("DrpCity")
mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("DrpCity"))
mySelect.select_by_visible_text("Pune")
waitForElementRemoved(removedElement, 10, .5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='txtPickUp']"))).send_keys("XYZ")
```

I don't know if this is the ***best*** way to deal with JavaScript `onchange load` events, but in my case, it has been very effective.

---

***To add on to this answer***: I have found that **waiting until element goes stale** does not always work when there are multiple load events, I have found that using that method along with using the below code works much more effectively to make sure these dynamic load events are complete: (I adapted the below code from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348600/selenium-wait-for-ajax-content-to-load-universal-approach))

```
# Wait for AJAX (Jquery or JS) dynamic page load events
class DynamicLoadState:
    def __call__(self, driver):
        LoadComplete = False
        JQueryLoadComplete = False
        JSLoadComplete = False
        try:
            if driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active") == 0: JQueryLoadComplete = True
        except Exception:
            # JQuery is not present on page
            JQueryLoadComplete = True
        if driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == 'complete': JSLoadComplete = True
        if JQueryLoadComplete and JSLoadComplete: LoadComplete = True
        return LoadComplete

def WaitForDynamicLoad(driver, WaitTime):
    WebDriverWait(driver, WaitTime).until(DynamicLoadState())

# Use the first method of waiting for the element to go stale
# then run this to make sure all loading is completed

WaitForDynamicLoad(driver, Counts.WaitTime)
```

Hope this helps keep someone from using `time.sleep()` in the future for page load!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comment **is to wait for the element that is affected by the load to go stale or not be found** did the _trick_.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

@PixelEinstein 's Answer is the working and accepted Answer as his idea to *wait for the element that is affected by the load to go stale or not be found* did the trick. Finally I have arrived to a solution through a much simpler way then it was expected. I had to simply wait for the *DELIVER ADDRESS* field to go **stale** and then invoke 'send_keys("XYZ")' again on *DELIVER ADDRESS* field as follows :

```
driver.get("https://www.avis.co.in")
mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("DrpCity"))
mySelect.select_by_visible_text("Pune")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtPickUp']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtPickUp']").send_keys("XYZ")
```

The discussion [**How to wait on the __doPostBack method to complete in javascript?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504472/how-to-wait-on-the-dopostback-method-to-complete-in-javascript) was helpful to understand `__doPostBack()`

### tl;dr

[**Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager endRequest Event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx)