# How Can I Wait Until Vue Finishes Processing?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, vue.js, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium to test a web page and sometimes it gets unreliable because it's still processing "Vue" and the code starts to look for elements on screen. But I should wait until vue finishes loading.

How Can I Wait Until Vue Finished Processing?

For example, while it's loading, I can see vue tags:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about waiting for specific element or the whole page?

Comment: Any case would work for me. I want to find an element, but wait until there are no "vue" tags on it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this method worth trying, by customizing expected condition for vue tag non-existence:

```
protected void waitForTagNonExistence(WebElement element) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), ELEMENT_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                return (element.getAttribute("v-touch:tap") == null);
            } catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `wait` function with the following `xPath`:

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsClickable(By.xpath("//img[not(@v-on:click = 'drop') and @src = 'img/end_call.svg']")), 15000);
```

The xPath uses `not` and `and`. `not` means that will be selected elements without `@v-on:click = 'drop'` attribute. `and` is to select an element with `@src = 'img/end_call.svg'` but not with `@v-on:click = 'drop'`

More information about `xPath` operators can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp).

Comment: @AutomatedOwl you are right. I have changed to clickable. Thank you for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, *Selenium* have no direct dependency whether the AUT<sup>1</sup> is built through either [**Vue.js**](https://vuejs.org/), [**ReactJS**](https://reactjs.org/) or [**JavaScript**](https://www.javascript.com/). From *Selenium* perspective what matters most is the different states (mentioned below) of an *WebElement* with whom you want to interact as follows:

- **`present`**
- **`visible`**
- **`interactable (i.e. clickable)`**

So basiaclly you need to induce a waiter i.e. *WebDriverWait* for the desired element to be in your desired state as follows:

- [**presence**](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf):

  ```
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  // Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be present on the dom.
  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('#abc')), 5000);
  ```
- [**visibility**](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf):

  ```
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  // Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be visible on the dom.
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#abc')), 5000);
  ```
- [**interactibility** (i.e. clickablity)](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable):

  ```
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  // Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be clickable.
  browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('#abc')), 5000);
  ```

As per the *HTML* you have shared to *wait* for the desired *element to be clickable* you can use the following solution:

```
browser.wait(until.elementIsClickable(By.xpath("//img[@src='img/end_call.svg']")), 20);
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>Application Under Test</sub>

---

### Update

As per your comment update, if the element becomes **interactable** I don't see any obstacle in sending the `character sequence`. However, if the `character sequence` disappears on *post Vue finish processing* we can use the `ExpectedConditions` as [**stalenessOf**](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf)

Here you can find a similar discussion on *JavaScript* `__doPostBack` in [**How do I wait for a JavaScript __doPostBack call through Selenium and WebDriver**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561611/how-do-i-wait-for-a-javascript-dopostback-call-through-selenium-and-webdriver)

Comment: sorry but I still should wait for the Vue to finish processing, because the page gets refreshed once it's done (that's 1 scenario). So Selenium can be unstable if it gets the element before the refresh is done.

Comment: @alansiqueira27 Checkout my answer update and let me know if that answers your question.