# web scraping for javascript __doPostBack contain a herf in td

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, dopostback

I want to scrape a website i.e. is `https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27=` using selenium but I am able to scrape only one page not other pages.

Here I am using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/ptiwar34/Documents/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities())
driver.get('https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27=')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td/a[text()='2']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td/a[text()='2']").click()

numLinks = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td/a[text()='2']"))))
print(numLinks)
for i in range(numLinks):
    print("Perform your scraping here on page {}".format(str(i+1)))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td/a[text()='2']/span//following::span[1]"))).click()
driver.quit()
```

here is the html content

```
    <td><span>1</span></td>
    <td><a 
     href="javascript:__doPostBack 
(&#39;dnn$ctr1535$UNSPSCSearch$gvDetailsSearchView&#39;,&#39;Page$2&#39;)" 
style="color:#333333;">2</a>
     </td>
```

This throws an error:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape the website `https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27=` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27=%27")
    while True:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[contains(@id, 'UNSPSCSearch_gvDetailsSearchView')]//tr[last()]//table//span//following::a[1]"))).click()
            print("Clicked for next page")
        except TimeoutException:
            print("No more pages")
            break
    driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
    Clicked for next page
    Clicked for next page
    Clicked for next page
    .
    .
    .
  ```
- Explaination: If you observe the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) the *page numbers* are within a `<table>` with a dynamic `id` attribute containing the text **UNSPSCSearch_gvDetailsSearchView**. Further the *page numbers* are within the **last** `<tr>` which is having a child `<table>`. With in the child table the *current page number* is within a `<span>` which holds the key. So to `click()` on the *next page number* you just need to identify the following `<a>` tag with index `[1]`. Finally, as the element is having `javascript:__doPostBack()` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How do I wait for a JavaScript __doPostBack call through Selenium and WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561611/how-do-i-wait-for-a-javascript-dopostback-call-through-selenium-and-webdriver)

Comment: could you help in scraping the code and title using beautiful soup for each page as i am using this for single page  unspsc_link = "https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27="    
   link = requests.get(unspsc_link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')
     right_table = soup.find('table', id="dnn_ctr1535_UNSPSCSearch_gvDetailsSearchView")
            df = pd.read_html(str(right_table))[0]
            # Clean up the DataFrame
            df = df[[0, 1]]
            df.columns = df.iloc[0]
            df = df[1:]
            print(df)

Comment: @AyushKangar Yup, that can be done. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: could you explain "//table[contains(@id, 'UNSPSCSearch_gvDetailsSearchView')]//tr[last()]//table//span//following::a[1]" how to choose the path  like  table span and following

Comment: @AyushKangar Added an explanation for the solution. let me know if any further queries.

Comment: after scrapping several pages @DebanjanB it throws error StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)

Comment: @AyushKangar Did you checkout the reference discussion I have added as a footnote within the answer? Does that help you?

Comment: hey @DebanjanB look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640584/scraping-a-website-using-selenium-for-each-product

Answer (score 0):

To find/click the page numbers you can use:

```
for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'UNSPSCSearch$gvDetailsSearchView')]"):
    if x.text.isdigit():
        print(x.text)
        #x.click()
        #...
```

---

Output:

`2`
`3`
`4`
...

---

Based on your comment, you can use:

```
max_pages = 10
for page_number in range(2, max_pages+1):
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'UNSPSCSearch$gvDetailsSearchView')]"):
        if x.text.isdigit():
            if int(x.strip()) == page_number:
                x.click()
                #parse results here
                break
```

Comment: when i run this how would i scrap the pages and when i uses this code till x.click() it throws error after mentioning 2 and 3 StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)

Comment: You've to add a controller to know in which page you are and parse the new page numbers.

Comment: I've posted an update. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, thank you!