# Python Selenium unable to locate an element after switching to frame using Firefox browser

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am not able to locate the element inside the frame after switching to the correct frame. Here is my code, error and HTML sorce. If I right click on the frame and select `This Frame -> Show Only This Frame` then I am able to find the element in the `default_content`, but I need to find it without `Show Only This Frame`

```
browser.switch_to.default_content()  

browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('DialogFrame'))

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#_ctl12_btnExportCSV')
```

Error stacktrace:

> NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#_ctl12_btnExportCSV')
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
> in find_element_by_css_selector(self, css_selector)
> 596             element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')
> 597         """
> --> 598         return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
> 599
> 600     def find_elements_by_css_selector(self, css_selector):
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
> in find_element(self, by, value)
> 974                 by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
> 975                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
> --> 976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
> 977             'using': by,
> 978             'value': value})['value']
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
> in execute(self, driver_command, params)
> 319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
> 320         if response:
> --> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> 322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
> 323                 response.get('value', None))
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py
> in check_response(self, response)
> 240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
> 241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
> --> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> 243
> 244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
>
> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
> #_ctl12_btnExportCSV

HTML:

[image: HTML nested]

[image: IFrame]

Answer (score 1):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'DialogFrame')))
inptelement=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#_ctl12_btnExportCSV')))
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

The element `#_ctl12_btnExportCSV` is a [__doPostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594334/web-scrapping-for-javascript-dopostback-contain-a-herf-in-td/57599603#57599603) enabled element.

As the element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"DialogFrame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id$='btnExportCSV'][name$='btnExportCSV'][value='Scaricamento']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"DialogFrame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'btnExportCSV') and contains(@name, 'btnExportCSV')][@value='Scaricamento']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thank you both but unfortunately the solutions are not working. There is a timeout error when locating the element: