# How to paginate through the page numbers when href contains javascript:__doPostBack()

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, dopostback

I'm trying to scrape this website http://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.ar.mfa?dcabec54-44b3-4aaa-a725-70d0caa8a0ae
but when I want to go to next page I can't because the link doesn't change 
you will find that pages links are like that

```
href="javascript:__doPostBack('sb$grd','Page$1')"
```

I have a code that I tried but it only goes to page 2 and then gave me an error: tale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'http://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.ar.mfa?dcabec54-44b3-4aaa-a725-70d0caa8a0ae'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
btn = [w for w in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sb_grd"]/tbody/tr[26]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a')]
for b in btn:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", b)
```

Comment: There's a form on the page (`name="form1"`), which is submitted when the link is activated. You could post such a form to the site, but if the request is not responded (or the response is the actual page), I suppose you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paginate through the page numbers with *href* attribute as `"javascript:__doPostBack('sb$grd','Page$2')"` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.ar.mfa?dcabec54-44b3-4aaa-a725-70d0caa8a0ae")
  while True:
      try:
          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='sb_grd']//table/tbody/tr//td/span//following::td[1]/a"))).click()
          print("Next page clicked")
      except TimeoutException:
          print("No more pages")
          break
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Next page clicked
  Next page clicked
  Next page clicked
  .
  .
  .
  No more pages
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How do I wait for a JavaScript __doPostBack call through Selenium and WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561611/how-do-i-wait-for-a-javascript-dopostback-call-through-selenium-and-webdriver)

Comment: Thank you it worked but i will need to study the code to understand it fully

Answer (score 0):

You can see that a request is made under the wood to this url : http://www.mfa.gov.tr/default.fr.mfa
Do F12 and go to the network tab to see that.

All the articles you need will be in the document at this url, you don't need to paginate as the pagination has just a purpose display. No request is being made by this pagination, expect to download the displayed image.

Comment: where i can find it ?
i opened network tab but couldn't find it