# Use Selenium to download file by clicking "javascript:__doPostBack('LeaderBoard1$cmdCSV','')"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, dopostback

There are a bunch of CSV files of baseball stats that I want to download via automation, which can be found at: https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=0&season=2020&month=0&season1=2020&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2020-01-01&enddate=2020-12-31. The button to download the table as a CSV is labeled 'Export Data'.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="br_dby">
    <span style="float: left">
        <a href="javascript:ShowHide();">Show Filters</a>  
            |  
        <a href="#custom">Custom Reports</a>
    </span>
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('LeaderBoard1$cmdCSV','')" id="LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV">Export Data</a>
</div>
```

As you can tell, the button is not a redirect to a download page (in which case `requests` could be used to download the file), but is a process.

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
binary = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.binary = binary
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", True)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r"C:\Users\jlpyt\Downloads")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r"C:\Users\jlpyt\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win32\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=0&season=2020&month=0&season1=2020&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2020-01-01&enddate=2020-12-31')
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV')
elem.click()
```

Using this code, *Selenium* is able to click the button, but no download is initiated. Is there some way that I can use *Selenium* to click the button and download the file? Or, is there some alternative method that I have not thought of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is [`__doPostBack`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561611/how-do-i-wait-for-a-javascript-dopostback-call-through-selenium-and-webdriver/49630571#49630571) enabled element, so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV"))).click()
  ```
- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Export Data"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='LeaderBoard1_cmdCSV']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: fangraphs]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [web scraping for javascript __doPostBack contain a herf in td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594334/web-scraping-for-javascript-dopostback-contain-a-herf-in-td/57599603#57599603)
- [How to paginate through the page numbers when href contains javascript:__doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374469/how-to-paginate-through-the-page-numbers-when-href-contains-javascript-dopostb/59377905#59377905)