# How I can use selenium to click at web element of this javascript:_doPostBack()

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I wonder how I can use selenium to click on web element "automation_quiz" at this `javascript:_doPostBack()`.

The following is a snippet from the html page:

```
<a id="ctl00_Content_tgv_ctl03_lbtCaption" title="click to launch automation_quiz" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$tgv$ctl03$lbtCaption','')">automation_quiz</a>
```

I could not find the Xpath of "automation_quiz" by using firefox Xpath-finder.

Comment: This is a snippet from the html page:                                                                                   <a id="ctl00_Content_tgv_ctl03_lbtCaption" title="click to launch automation_quiz" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$tgv$ctl03$lbtCaption','')">automation_quiz</a>

Comment: //a[@id="ctl00_Content_tgv_ctl03_lbtCaption"]

Comment: //a[text()='automation_quiz']

Answer (score -1):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `Click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `LinkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("automation_quiz"))).Click();
  ```
- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("a[title='click to launch automation_quiz'][href*='Content'][id$='lbtCaption']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[@title='click to launch automation_quiz' and text()='automation_quiz']"))).Click();
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [web scraping for javascript __doPostBack contain a herf in td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594334/web-scrapping-for-javascript-dopostback-contain-a-herf-in-td/57599603#57599603)
- [How to paginate through the page numbers when href contains javascript:__doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374469/how-to-paginate-through-the-page-numbers-when-href-contains-javascript-dopostb/59377905#59377905)
- [How do I wait for a JavaScript __doPostBack call through Selenium and WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561611/how-do-i-wait-for-a-javascript-dopostback-call-through-selenium-and-webdriver)
- [Use Selenium to download file by clicking "javascript:__doPostBack('LeaderBoard1$cmdCSV','')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864801/use-selenium-to-download-file-by-clicking-javascript-dopostbackleaderboard1/63864928#63864928)

Comment: It works using CssSelector mode! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, you cannot find web elements by JavaScript methods initiated in their click with Selenium. Also unfortunate is that there is no current alternative to Selenium for navigating dynamic content. Check the documentation for other web element search methods. If you can’t find by Xpath, maybe you could locate using html ID or similar. If not, try using the ChromeDriver instead of Firefox. I’ve had much less trouble using Xpaths on chrome.