# How to click on __doPostBack enabled Update button with no ID using C# Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, dopostback

How to click Update button with no ID using C# Selenium?

```
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder8$GridView1','Update$0')">
```

I used the code below but it does not work:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder8_GridView1']/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/input")).Click();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is n [__doPostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864801/use-selenium-to-download-file-by-clicking-javascript-dopostbackleaderboard1/63864928#63864928) enabled element. So to `Click()` on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input[value='Update'][onclick*='ContentPlaceHolder']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@value='Update' and contains(@onclick, 'ContentPlaceHolder')]"))).Click();
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [web scraping for javascript __doPostBack contain a herf in td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594334/web-scraping-for-javascript-dopostback-contain-a-herf-in-td/57599603#57599603)
- [How do I wait for a JavaScript __doPostBack call through Selenium and WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561611/how-do-i-wait-for-a-javascript-dopostback-call-through-selenium-and-webdriver)
- [How to paginate through the page numbers when href contains javascript:__doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374469/how-to-paginate-through-the-page-numbers-when-href-contains-javascript-dopostb/59377905#59377905)