# Python Selenium Timeout Exception when scraping from dynamically loaded table within an iframe

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape from a dynamically loaded table using Selenium

Since it is dynamically loaded by javascript, I need to use Webdriverwait but I am keep getting

Timeout exception errors

My code is as below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome("my_path")
import time


URL = r'https://www.customs.go.jp/toukei/srch/indexe.htm?M=09&P=1,2,,,,,,,,1,0,2020,0,10,0,2,440131,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,200'

driver.get(URL)



data = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".value")))
print(data.text)
```

I have searching through all possible ways to do the WebDriverWait, but all the below options did not work

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until_not(EC.title_is(title))
driver.set_script_timeout(10)
time.sleep(10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="test"]')))
```

My ultimate goal is to scrape the table from the URL.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element `#_ctl12_btnExportCSV` is a [`__doPostBack`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630571/7429447) enabled element.

As the element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.customs.go.jp/toukei/srch/indexe.htm?M=09&P=1,2,,,,,,,,1,0,2020,0,10,0,2,440131,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,200')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"FR_M_INFO")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.value"))).text)
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.customs.go.jp/toukei/srch/indexe.htm?M=09&P=1,2,,,,,,,,1,0,2020,0,10,0,2,440131,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,200')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"TopPage")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='value']"))).text)
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  CUSTOMS UNIT1 UNIT2 CURRENT MONTH CUMULATIVE YEAR TO DATE
  QUANTITY1 QUANTITY2 VALUE QUANTITY1 QUANTITY2 VALUE
  4401.31-000
  (105 CHINA)TOTAL   MT   46 2516   350 17871
  100 TOKYO   MT   - -   26 1458
  200 YOKOHAMA   MT   - -   5 285
  260 SENDAISHIOGAMA   MT   5 268   27 1544
  370 MATSUYAMA   MT   7 382   43 2363
  400 OSAKA   MT   17 945   67 4135
  402 OSAKA SAKAI   MT   - -   102 3603
  500 NAGOYA   MT   11 610   57 3211
  803 TOMAKOMAI   MT   - -   17 961
  804 OTARU   MT   6 311   6 311
  (110 VIETNAM)TOTAL   MT   52761 834897   819727 14059241
  100 TOKYO   MT   78 1824   1066 18003
  200 YOKOHAMA   MT   155 2123   3579 53269
  243 KASHIMA   MT   - -   60782 988066
  244 HITACHI   MT   14300 219359   142892 2425105
  250 ONAHAMA   MT   - -   53262 890457
  252 SOOMA   MT   - -   23196 407325
  260 SENDAISHIOGAMA   MT   - -   3058 33513
  262 ISHINOMAKI   MT   - -   30570 585228
  300 KOBE   MT   - -   156 2753
  342 FUKUYAMA   MT   - -   341 7919
  352 HAMADA   MT   - -   20 362
  370 MATSUYAMA   MT   - -   23 432
  400 OSAKA   MT   - -   14 307
  500 NAGOYA   MT   14 209   14 209
  505 KINUURA   MT   - -   49001 751832
  520 SHIMIZU   MT   - -   10 278
  540 YOKKAICHI   MT   - -   94539 1649611
  600 MOJI   MT   21820 348327   57148 921286
  603 TOBATA   MT   9580 158030   208229 3741854
  604 HAKATA   MT   - -   60 996
  620 SHIMONOSEKI   MT   - -   20 222
  660 OOITA   MT   - -   45979 864566
  670 HOSOJIMA   MT   - -   10433 148152
  750 KAGOSHIMA   MT   6300 96702   31200 496288
  754 SHIBUSHI   MT   154 2562   560 9606
  755 SENDAI   MT   260 3986   1972 31489
  803 TOMAKOMAI   MT   52 908   547 10816
  807 KUSHIRO   MT   - -   618 11181
  822 HACHINOHE   MT   - -   78 1276
  842 KAMAISHI   MT   - -   168 3231
  900 OKINAWA CHIKU   MT   48 867   192 3609
  (111 THAILND)TOTAL   MT   - -   11091 220690
  244 HITACHI   MT   - -   10552 200467
  370 MATSUYAMA   MT   - -   29 446
  624 TOKUYAMA   MT   - -   510 19777
  (113 MALYSIA)TOTAL   MT   486 6944   77339 1366094
  243 KASHIMA   MT   - -   22000 326139
  322 MIZUSHIMA   MT   - -   25 371
  603 TOBATA   MT   - -   11319 218308
  623 UBE   MT   - -   1751 30598
  660 OOITA   MT   - -   34766 689086
  670 HOSOJIMA   MT   - -   3544 44067
  754 SHIBUSHI   MT   - -   76 1107
  803 TOMAKOMAI   MT   - -   51 778
  822 HACHINOHE   MT   486 6944   3807 55640
  (117 PHILPIN)TOTAL   MT   - -   77 656
  345 HIROSHIMA   MT   - -   77 656
  (118 INDNSIA)TOTAL   MT   332 5448   13731 218740
  200 YOKOHAMA   MT   50 747   555 8707
  260 SENDAISHIOGAMA   MT   - -   312 4894
  300 KOBE   MT   - -   25 410
  322 MIZUSHIMA   MT   - -   234 3739
  500 NAGOYA   MT   128 2120   1162 20451
  505 KINUURA   MT   - -   10090 157615
  803 TOMAKOMAI   MT   101 1747   348 6182
  822 HACHINOHE   MT   53 834   1005 16742
  (203 SWEDEN)TOTAL   MT   - -   6 1070
  400 OSAKA   MT   - -   6 1070
  (224 RUSSIA)TOTAL   MT   - -   25 441
  803 TOMAKOMAI   MT   - -   25 441
  (235 ESTONIA)TOTAL   MT   - -   23 641
  500 NAGOYA   MT   - -   23 641
  (302 CANADA)TOTAL   MT   67190 1365696   492185 9981576
  100 TOKYO   MT   - -   221 6918
  140 SAKATA   MT   - -   69000 1426484
  250 ONAHAMA   MT   - -   20200 422807
  252 SOOMA   MT   21000 421282   83027 1672320
  262 ISHINOMAKI   MT   - -   72876 1558082
  300 KOBE   MT   - -   585 13187
  400 OSAKA   MT   - -   211 4208
  430 MAIZURU   MT   7637 141124   7637 141124
  505 KINUURA   MT   - -   133377 2522015
  623 UBE   MT   - -   41403 881231
  624 TOKUYAMA   MT   10000 206451   30498 620841
  628 IWAKUNI   MT   28000 582954   28000 582954
  754 SHIBUSHI   MT   - -   50 1327
  803 TOMAKOMAI   MT   527 13184   4997 125268
  900 OKINAWA CHIKU   MT   26 701   103 2810
  (304 USA)TOTAL   MT   - -   31 2678
  202 KAWASAKI   MT   - -   2 255
  300 KOBE   MT   - -   0 230
  372 IMABARI   MT   - -   29 2193
  (601 AUSTRAL)TOTAL   MT   - -   70 5362
  352 HAMADA   MT   - -   10 742
  700 NAGASAKI   MT   - -   60 4620
  (606 NEWZELD)TOTAL   MT   - -   37 1650
  200 YOKOHAMA   MT   - -   9 925
  300 KOBE   MT   - -   28 725
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847390/7429447)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Comment: Thank you so much!! It has really been useful. If you have the time, can I ask you one further question from here? Is there any possible way to convert the text to a data frame so that it is easy to handle?

Comment: @Hanalia Apologies, rarely I deal with _data frame_. Feel free to raise a new question on SO.